# The "Aggregate" function from excel to DAX power BI, or search for the maximum date with conditions from another table

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have 2 tables A and B. A has a one-to-many relationship with B.
Table B has the start and end dates.
Table A is created from Table B, grouped by the column "work group" (group_work_sch = SUMMARIZE('Schedule of types of work', [Section], [Group of works]))
In table A, you need to pull up the minimum date from table A, taking into account the group of works.
In excel i could do it like: =aggregate(15;6;'Table_B'!$D$3:$D$1173/('Table_B'!$B$3:$B$1173='table_A'!B2);1)
expamle:
Table B:
[image]

Table A as result:
[image]

How could i do it in power bi DAX?
now, i create table A and link it to table B.
I have to add 2 columns in table A and get dates.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try:

```
First Start Date = CALCULATE( MIN(TableB[Start Date]) )
```

```
Last End Date = CALCULATE( MAX(TableB[End Date]) )
```

Comment: but this does not take into account the types of work, for example, work_1 and work_2 will put the same date

Comment: Have you tried it? The relationship will take care of that.